# Translating a Latin phrase from an animated show

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, passage-identification

I remember a cartoon show named "Gargoyles" (follow [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gargoyles_(TV_series)) please) I used to see when I was young.
The hero there used to use a sort of magic tool to travel through time.
He used to say something like "Les tegratte, muri tempe, at intervalia".
I don't know Latin, I thought these words were Latin. 
I want to know the meaning of these words in English please.

If someone knows, that could bring some relief to me when I remember that scene with my brother (we used to see that cartoon together).
I would like to mention that it was dubbed in Arabic (I'm Lebanese). I'm still hoping they've dubbed it right.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you can listen to the phrase [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q8oAeHWG6Fk&t=14m28s).
To me it sounds like "tesla grate muri tempi et intervalia".
It sounds like an attempt at something that sounds like Latin, but it doesn't quite make sense.

Perhaps the last four words are supposed to be something like "intervals and walls of time".
The word *grate* means "thankfully" or "willingly".
I'm not sure if the "tesla" is supposed to refer to the accompanying visual effects, contain *des* (as "please give"), or something else.
I might also have misheard something.

Anyway, I don't think it's proper Latin.
It might make sense in some other language, but I can't quite parse it.

---

Upon reading Hugh's answer, I realize that what I heard as "tesla" was "defla".
It seems to be "deflagrate muri tempi et intervalia" or something similar.

To make it proper Latin, you'd need to do the following modifications:

- The walls should be in accusative, *muros*.
- The genitive of *tempus* is not *tempi* but *temporis*. Not every Latin word ending in *-us* is declined the same way!
- The correct spelling of "intervals" is *intervalla*. It's second declension, not third.

If you modify the phrase to this, I'd be happier to accept it as Latin:

> Deflagrate muros temporis et intervalla!
>   Burn down the walls and intervals of time!

Comment: @YoussefDir: do you remember the Arabic phrase it was dubbed in? I did Arabic as a minor and know enough about the grammar to be able to use a dictionary. If I can combine my knowledge of Latin and Arabic, we might get a step closer.

Comment: Actually I'm a bit confused with Tesla gratte, but I guess it was Leste Gratte, as denoted in the question.

Comment: @YoussefDir I'd say it was *deflagrate* all along. But the pronunciation isn't very clear.

Answer (score 2):

Mixing Youssef's version and Joonas's
with what I could hear, I guessed the Latin was being mixed with back-slang.
"Tes stegrat" 'spells' Targets Set!

But almost all the other Gargoyle formulae are in Latin, or something like it.

Even so there is uncertainty about the  incantation for the Phoenix Gate. This version (collected by G.Guay for Katrina Dawn Nell) appears with two other versions on [The Gargoyles fans Website](http://www.gargoyles-fans.org/characters/spells.htm):

> *“Deflagrate muri tempi et intervallia!”*
>   Burn down walls of time and space!

Comment: *Deflagrate* is a good idea! I updated my answer using that, and gave you a +1.